# Django class-based user authentication

Tags: python, django

i've been searching for days the way to create a class based user authentication based on **'auth.User'** Model like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    categoria_post = models.ForeignKey('Categoria')
    descripion = models.TextField()
    imagen = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titulo

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.titulo)
            super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

But in my **views.py** i'm doing something like this:

```
class login(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = get.POST.request['username']
        password = get.POST.request['password']
```

I think that's the wrong way, also guys if you can tell me if i should use class-based or functions please, thank so much guys for the support!

Comment: i'm confused why you posted a `Post` model. What does that have to do with authentication that you're trying to do?

Comment: @awwester Because i'm trying to make a reference about the login / sign in i want to make based on ('auth.User')